# How to use multiple background images in a sweetalert2 queue

Tags: sweetalert, simplemodal, sweetalert2

I need to change background images as the modal keeps going foward. I-m using background property inside the queue but it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

OK I just realized I was changing background modal image through css, right way to do it is via background property inside every queue step. Dumb me.